# Geometry on Isosceles Triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

As shown in the figure, $$\overline{BD}=\overline{DE}=\overline{AE}\\\overline{EH}=\overline{HF}=\overline{FI}=\overline{IG}=\overline{GC}$$
Where $\overline{EH}$ is the bisector of $\angle AEC$.
What is the ratio of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ ($\frac{\angle B}{\angle C}$) in degrees?
[image: Figure]

---

I put all the statements on the figure, but it doesn't seem to give me much useful information.

I also tried to assume a specific angle (for example, $\angle B$) to be some unknown angle $x$, but even with a lot of isosceles triangles given, there are still a lot of unknown anges.

Comment: Where is the figure?

Comment: $\angle DBE=x$, $\angle ADE=2x$, $\angle AEF=3x$, ... $\angle GCI=y$, $\angle IGF=2y$, $\angle FIH=3y$, $\angle HFE=4y$. Hence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\angle B = x$ and $\angle C = y$.

We have $\angle DEB = x$, and thus $\angle EDA = 2x$. $\angle DAE$ is $2x$ as well.

On the right we have $\angle GIC = y$. Hence $\angle IGF = 2y$, and so is $\angle IFG$.

Now $\angle FIH = 180^\circ - \angle FIG - \angle GIC = 180^\circ - (180^\circ - 2y - 2y) - y = 3y = \angle FHI$.

Similarly, $\angle HFE = \angle HEF = \angle HEA = 4y$.

Considering the angles at $E$, we have:

$$180^\circ = \angle BED + \angle DEA + \angle AEH + \angle HEF = x + (180^\circ - 4x)+4y+4y$$

Therefore $3x = 8y \leadsto \dfrac {\angle B}{\angle C} = \dfrac 83$.

Comment: Or you can just say that $\angle HIF=\angle IFC+\angle ICF=2x+x=3x$. The answer would be a bit shorter this way.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ to be $y$ and $x$ respectively.

By angle chasing,  you can show that $\angle AEB=180-3y$ and $\angle  HEC=4x$. Since $EH$ bisects $\angle AEC$, $\angle AEC=8x$

$\Rightarrow   3y=8x$

$\Rightarrow   \frac{\angle B}{\angle C}=\frac{y}{x}=\boxed {\frac{8}{3}}$